# Android notification is not showing in the background

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

app is open Notification is showing but app is in the background Notification is not showing
The notification should be working 8 , but android 9,10  not working. The Notification isn't showing at all. I don't know what am I missing.

this is a MyFCMservise file

```
class MyFCMService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    private var fireManager = FireManager()
    private var disposables = CompositeDisposable()
    private lateinit var newMessageHandler: NewMessageHandler

    private val parentJob = SupervisorJob()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Main + parentJob)


   

    


    override fun onNewToken(s: String) {
        super.onNewToken(s)
        if (!isLoggedIn()) return 


        SharedPreferencesManager.setTokenSaved(false)
        ServiceHelper.saveToken(this, s)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
        if (FireManager.isLoggedIn()
                .not()
        ) return  
        if (updateChecker.needsUpdate()) return

        val mainHandler = Handler(mainLooper)
        //run on main thread
        val myRunnable = Runnable {
            newMessageHandler = NewMessageHandler(this, fireManager, messageDecryptor, disposables)



            if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey("event")) {
                
                when {
                    remoteMessage.data["event"] == "group_event" -> {
                        handleGroupEvent(remoteMessage)
                    }
                    remoteMessage.data["event"] == "new_group" -> {
                        handleNewGroup(remoteMessage)
                    }
                    remoteMessage.data["event"] == "message_deleted" -> {
                        handleDeletedMessage(remoteMessage)
                    }
                    remoteMessage.data["event"] == "new_call" -> {
                        handleNewCall(remoteMessage)
                    }

                    remoteMessage.data["event"] == "logout" -> {
                        val newDeviceId = remoteMessage.data["deviceId"]

                        if (newDeviceId != null && newDeviceId != DeviceId.id) {
                            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                                .sendBroadcast(Intent(IntentUtils.ACTION_LOGOUT))
                            FireManager.logout()
                            NotificationHelper(this).fireUserLoggedOutNotification()
                        }
                    }

                }
            } else {
                if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey(DBConstants.MESSAGE_ID)) {
                    handleNewMessage(remoteMessage)
                }
            }
        }
        mainHandler.post(myRunnable)
    }

    private fun handleNewCall(map: RemoteMessage) {
        val data = map.data

        data["callId"]?.let { callId ->


            val fromId = data["callerId"] ?: ""

            val typeInt = data["callType"]?.toIntOrNull() ?: CallType.VOICE.value
            val type = CallType.fromInt(typeInt)


            val groupId = data["groupId"] ?: ""

            val isGroupCall = type.isGroupCall()

            if (!isGroupCall && uid.isEmpty()) return@let
            if (isGroupCall && groupId.isEmpty()) return@let
            val channel = data["channel"] ?: return@let

            val groupName = data["groupName"] ?: ""

            val timestamp = data["timestamp"]?.toLongOrNull() ?: System.currentTimeMillis()
            val phoneNumber = data["phoneNumber"] ?: ""

            val isVideo = type.isVideo()

            val uid = if (isGroupCall) groupId else fromId


            var user: User

            val storedUser = RealmHelper.getInstance().getUser(uid)

            if (storedUser == null) {
                //make dummy user temporarily
                user = User().apply {
                    if (isGroupCall) {
                        this.uid = groupId!!
                        this.isGroupBool = true
                        this.userName = groupName
                        this.group = Group().apply {
                            this.groupId = groupId
                            this.isActive = true
                            this.setUsers(mutableListOf(SharedPreferencesManager.getCurrentUser()))
                        }

                    } else {
                        this.uid = uid
                        this.phone = phoneNumber
                    }
                }
            } else {
                user = storedUser
            }

            val fireCall = FireCall(
                callId,
                user,
                FireCallDirection.INCOMING,
                timestamp,
                phoneNumber,
                isVideo,
                typeInt,
                channel
            )


            newMessageHandler.handleNewCall(fireCall)

        }

    }

    private fun handleNewMessage(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val messageId = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.MESSAGE_ID]

        //if message is deleted do not save it
        if (RealmHelper.getInstance().getDeletedMessage(messageId) != null) return
        if (RealmHelper.getInstance().getTempMessage(messageId) != null) return


        val isGroup = remoteMessage.data.containsKey("isGroup")
        //getting data from fcm message and convert it to a message
        val phone = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.PHONE] ?: ""
        val content = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.CONTENT]
        val timestamp = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.TIMESTAMP]
        val type = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.TYPE]?.toInt() ?: 0
        //get sender uid
        val fromId = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.FROM_ID]
        val toId = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.TOID]
        val metadata = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.METADATA]
        val partialText = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.PARTIAL_TEXT]

        

        //if it's a group message and the message sender is the same
        if (fromId == uid) return

        //create the message
        val message = Message()
        message.content = content
        message.partialText = partialText
        message.timestamp = timestamp

        message.fromId = fromId
        message.type = convertedType
        message.messageId = messageId
        message.metadata = metadata
        message.toId = toId
        val chatId = if (isGroup) toId else fromId
        message.chatId = chatId
        message.isGroup = isGroup
        if (isGroup) message.fromPhone = phone
        //set default state
        message.downloadUploadStat = DownloadUploadStat.FAILED

       
        if (MessageType.isSentText(type)) {
            //set the state to default
            message.downloadUploadStat = DownloadUploadStat.DEFAULT
} else if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey(DBConstants.LOCATION)) {


            message.downloadUploadStat = DownloadUploadStat.DEFAULT
            //get the json location as String
            val lat = remoteMessage.data["lat"] ?: ""
            val lng = remoteMessage.data["lng"] ?: ""
            if (lat.isNotEmpty() && lng.isNotEmpty()) {
                val name = remoteMessage.data["name"] ?: ""
                val address = remoteMessage.data["address"] ?: ""
                val location = RealmLocation(address, name, lat, lng)
                message.location = location
            }
        } else if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey(DBConstants.THUMB)) {
            val thumb = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.THUMB]

            //Check if it's Video and set Video Duration
            if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey(DBConstants.MEDIADURATION)) {
                val mediaDuration = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.MEDIADURATION]
                message.mediaDuration = mediaDuration
            }
            message.thumb = thumb


            //check if it's Voice Message or Audio File
        } else if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey(DBConstants.MEDIADURATION)
            && type == MessageType.SENT_VOICE_MESSAGE || type == MessageType.SENT_AUDIO
        ) {

            //set audio duration
            val mediaDuration = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.MEDIADURATION]
            message.mediaDuration = mediaDuration

            //check if it's a File
        } else if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey(DBConstants.FILESIZE)) {
            val fileSize = remoteMessage.data[DBConstants.FILESIZE]
            message.fileSize = fileSize
        }

        
        if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey("quotedMessageId")) {
            val quotedMessageId = remoteMessage.data["quotedMessageId"]
            
            RealmHelper.getInstance().refresh()
            val quotedMessage = RealmHelper.getInstance().getMessage(quotedMessageId, chatId)
            if (quotedMessage != null)
                message.quotedMessage = QuotedMessage.messageToQuotedMessage(quotedMessage)
        }

        
        if (remoteMessage.data.containsKey("statusId")) {
            val statusId = remoteMessage.data["statusId"]
            
            RealmHelper.getInstance().refresh()
            val status = RealmHelper.getInstance().getStatus(statusId)
            if (status != null) {
                message.status = status
                val quotedMessage = Status.statusToMessage(status, fromId)
                quotedMessage?.fromId = uid
                quotedMessage?.chatId = fromId
                if (quotedMessage != null)
                    message.quotedMessage = QuotedMessage.messageToQuotedMessage(quotedMessage)


            }
            
        }


        scope.launch(Main) {
            newMessageHandler.handleNewMessage(phone, message)
        }


    }

    private fun handleDeletedMessage(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        newMessageHandler.handleDeletedMessage(remoteMessage.data)
    }

    private fun handleNewGroup(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        newMessageHandler.handleNewGroup(remoteMessage.data)
    }

    private fun handleGroupEvent(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        newMessageHandler.handleGroupEvent(remoteMessage.data)
    }


    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        disposables.dispose()
        cancelCoroutineJob()
    }

    private fun cancelCoroutineJob() = try {
//        parentJob.cancel()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

Notification Builder

```
public class NotificationHelper extends ContextWrapper {

    
    

    private NotificationManager manager;


    public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
        super(base);
        
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            NotificationChannel messagesChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_MESSAGES,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_MESSAGES, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            messagesChannel.setVibrationPattern(getVibrationPattern());
            getManager().createNotificationChannel(messagesChannel);

            NotificationChannel audioChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_AUDIO,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_AUDIO, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            audioChannel.setSound(null, null);

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(audioChannel);


            NotificationChannel callsChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_CALLING,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_CALLING, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            callsChannel.setSound(null, null);

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(callsChannel);


            NotificationChannel incomingCallsChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_INCOMING_CALLS,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_INCOMING_CALLS, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            incomingCallsChannel.setSound(null, null);

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(incomingCallsChannel);

            NotificationChannel backupChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_BACKUP,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_BACKUP, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            backupChannel.setSound(null, null);

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(backupChannel);


            NotificationChannel restoreChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_RESTORE,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME_RESTORE, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            restoreChannel.setSound(null, null);

            getManager().createNotificationChannel(restoreChannel);



        }
    }

    private long[] getVibrationPattern() {
        return SharedPreferencesManager.isVibrateEnabled() ? new long[]{200, 200} : new long[0];
    }


    //get summary text (30 messages from 2 chats for example)
    private String getSubText(int messagesCount, int chatsCount) {
        String chats = chatsCount == 1 ? " Chat" : " Chats";
        String messages = messagesCount == 1 ? " Message" : " Messages";
        if (chatsCount <= 1) {
            return messagesCount + " New " + messages;
        }
        return messagesCount + messages + " from " + chatsCount + chats;
    }

    private String getUserNameWithNumOfMessages(int unreadCount,
                                                String userName) {
        if (unreadCount == 0 || unreadCount == 1)
            return userName;

        return userName + " " + "(" + unreadCount + " Messages" + ")" + " ";

    }

    public static boolean isBelowApi24() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24;
    }


    private Bitmap getProfilePhotoAsBitmap(String thumbImg) {
        if (thumbImg != null)
            return BitmapUtils.encodeImage(thumbImg);

        
        
        return BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(this, R.drawable.user_img);

    }

    private String getSenderName(String userName, String groupName) {

        if (isBelowApi24() && groupName != null) {
            return userName + " @ " + groupName;
        }


        return userName;
    }

    
    public void dismissNotification(String chatId, boolean decrementCount) {

        Chat chat = RealmHelper.getInstance().getChat(chatId);
        if (chat != null) {

            int notificationId = isBelowApi24() ? ID_NOTIFICATION : chat.getNotificationId();
            getManager().cancel(notificationId);
            if (decrementCount) {
                updateNotificationCount(0);
                RealmHelper.getInstance().deleteUnReadMessages(chatId);
            }
            
            if (!isBelowApi24() && !RealmHelper.getInstance().areThereUnreadChats()) {
                
                getManager().cancel(ID_GROUP_NOTIFICATION);
            }
        }
    }

    //update Notification Count badge (in launcher)
    public void updateNotificationCount(int messagesCount) {

        if (messagesCount >= 0) {
            ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, messagesCount);
        }
    }


    public void fireNotification(String newMessageChatId) {
        boolean isNotificationsEnabled = SharedPreferencesManager.isNotificationEnabled();
        long unreadMessagesCount = RealmHelper.getInstance().getUnreadMessagesCount();
if (isBelowApi24()) {
            
            HashMap<String, Chat> chatHashMap = new HashMap<>();
            
            List<Message> last7UnreadMessages = RealmHelper.getInstance().getLast7UnreadMessages();
            final NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle messagingStyle = new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle("");
            
            int chatsCount = (int) RealmHelper.getInstance().getUnreadChatsCount();
            String lastMessageTimestamp;

            Chat lastChat;

            
            if (last7UnreadMessages.isEmpty()) {
                getManager().cancel(ID_NOTIFICATION);
            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < last7UnreadMessages.size(); i++) {

                    Message unreadMessage = last7UnreadMessages.get(i);

                    String chatId = unreadMessage.getChatId();
                    Chat chat;
                    
                    if (chatHashMap.containsKey(chatId)) {
                        chat = chatHashMap.get(chatId);
                        
                    } else {
                        chat = RealmHelper.getInstance().getChat(chatId);
                        chatHashMap.put(chatId, chat);
                    }

                    lastChat = chat;

                    lastMessageTimestamp = unreadMessage.getTimestamp();

                    
                   
                    if (isNotificationsEnabled && !chat.isMuted()) {
                        String sender = "";
                        if (chat.getUser().isGroupBool()) {
                            RealmList<User> users = chat.getUser().getGroup().getUsers();
                            User user = ListUtil.getUserById(unreadMessage.getFromId(), users);
                            if (user != null) {
                                sender = getSenderName(user.getProperUserName(), chat.getUser().getProperUserName());
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (chatsCount > 1)
                                sender = getSenderName(chat.getUser().getProperUserName(), null);
                        }

                        messagingStyle.addMessage(getMessageContent(unreadMessage, true), Long.parseLong(unreadMessage.getTimestamp()), sender);

                    }


                    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                            createNotificationBuilder(
                                    ""
                                    , ""
                                    , chat, chatsCount);


                    if (chatHashMap.size() > 1) {
                        String appName = this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
                        messagingStyle.setConversationTitle(appName);
                        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(null));

                    } else {
                        messagingStyle.setConversationTitle(lastChat.getUser().getProperUserName());
                        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(lastChat));
                    }


                    notificationBuilder.setSubText(getSubText((int) unreadMessagesCount, chatsCount));


                    notificationBuilder.setStyle(messagingStyle);

                    //set the timestamp of the last message
                    if (!lastMessageTimestamp.equals(""))
                        notificationBuilder.setWhen(Long.parseLong(lastMessageTimestamp));


                    //notify once after filling the messages
                    if (i == last7UnreadMessages.size() - 1)
                        getManager().notify(ID_NOTIFICATION, notificationBuilder.build());
                }
            }

            updateNotificationCount((int) unreadMessagesCount);

            //api24+ (grouping feature)
        } else {

            List<Chat> unreadChats = RealmHelper.getInstance().getUnreadChats();

            for (Chat unreadChat : unreadChats) {

                final NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
                final NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle messagingStyle = new NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle("");

                if (isNotificationsEnabled && !unreadChat.isMuted()) {


                    String userNameWithNumOfMessages = getUserNameWithNumOfMessages(unreadChat.getUnReadCount(), unreadChat.getUser().getProperUserName());

                    messagingStyle.setConversationTitle(userNameWithNumOfMessages);


                    //if it's a group or it's below api24 we will use messaging style
                    boolean isGroup = unreadChat.getUser().isGroupBool();

                    List<Message> messageList = RealmHelper.getInstance().filterUnreadMessages(unreadChat.getUnreadMessages());
                    if (isGroup) {
                        RealmList<User> users = unreadChat.getUser().getGroup().getUsers();

                        for (Message unreadMessage : messageList) {
                            User user = ListUtil.getUserById(unreadMessage.getFromId(), users);
                            if (user != null) {
                                String sender = getSenderName(user.getProperUserName(), unreadChat.getUser().getProperUserName());
                                messagingStyle.addMessage(getMessageContent(unreadMessage, true), Long.parseLong(unreadMessage.getTimestamp()), sender);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        for (Message unreadMessage : messageList) {
                            inboxStyle.addLine(getMessageContent(unreadMessage, true));
                        }
                    }


                    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                            createNotificationBuilder(
                                    userNameWithNumOfMessages
                                    , getMessageContent(unreadChat.getUnreadMessages().last(), true)
                                    , unreadChat, unreadChats.size());

                    //if it's a group we will use messaging style,otherwise we will user inboxStyle
                    notificationBuilder.setStyle(isGroup || isBelowApi24() ? messagingStyle : inboxStyle);

                    if (!unreadChat.getLastMessageTimestamp().equals(""))
                        notificationBuilder.setWhen(Long.parseLong(unreadChat.getLastMessageTimestamp()));


                    NotificationCompat.Builder groupNotification;

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(unreadChat);
                    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                    
                    notificationBuilder.setOnlyAlertOnce(newMessageChatId.equals(unreadChat.getChatId()) ? false : true);


                    int notificationId = unreadChat.getNotificationId();
                    //group multiple notification in one grouped notification
                    groupNotification = createNotificationBuilder("", "", null, unreadChats.size());

                    if (!unreadChat.getLastMessageTimestamp().equals(""))
                        groupNotification.setWhen(Long.parseLong(unreadChat.getLastMessageTimestamp()));


                    //group notification by user id
                    groupNotification.setGroupSummary(true).setGroup(KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP);

                    
                    groupNotification.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

                    groupNotification.setContentTitle("");

                    //set Summary (eg. 10 Messages from 3 Chat)
                    String subText = getSubText((int) unreadMessagesCount, unreadChats.size());

                    groupNotification.setSubText(subText);

                    notificationBuilder.setGroup(KEY_NOTIFICATION_GROUP);


                    notificationBuilder.addAction(getReplyActionInput(unreadChat));
                    notificationBuilder.addAction(getMarkAsReadAction(unreadChat));


                    getManager().notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
                    getManager().notify(ID_GROUP_NOTIFICATION, groupNotification.build());

                }
            }
            updateNotificationCount((int) unreadMessagesCount);
        }

    }


    //get onClick intent
    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Chat chat) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        if (isBelowApi24()) {
            //if it's only from one user then open the chatActivity with this user
            if (chat != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(IntentUtils.UID, chat.getChatId());
                //adding stack for user (to prevent kill the app when click back since there is no previous activity launched
                TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
                pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(ID_NOTIFICATION, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            } else {
                
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }

        } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(IntentUtils.UID, chat.getChatId());
            
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent);
            pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(chat.getNotificationId(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
        return pendingIntent;
    }

    private NotificationCompat.Builder createNotificationBuilder(
            String title, String message, Chat chat, int chatsCount) {


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID_MESSAGES)
                //set app icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_noti_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                //color
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                //Notification Sound (get it from shared preferences)
                .setSound(SharedPreferencesManager.getRingtone())
                //high priority to make it show as heads-up
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                //set vibrate if it's enabled by the user
                .setVibrate(getVibrationPattern());

        if (chat != null) {
            User user = chat.getUser();
            Bitmap largeIcon = getProfilePhotoAsBitmap(user.getThumbImg());

            if (!isBelowApi24() || chatsCount == 1)
                builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);

        } else {
            Bitmap largeIcon = getProfilePhotoAsBitmap(null);
            builder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
        }


        return builder;
    }

    private NotificationManager getManager() {
        if (manager == null) {
            manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
        return manager;
    }
```

app is open Notification is showing but app is in the background Notification is not showing